# Duplicate result is coming with SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query written below. It is giving me same value two times. Please have a look

```
SELECT distinct T0.[ItemCode],T0.[Dscription] ,T0.[Project],  T0.[Quantity] as [Recipts], T0.[DocDate], T0.[Project], T1.[Quantity] as [Issues] ,(T0.[Quantity] -T1.[Quantity]) as 'ABC' 
FROM [dbo].[IGN1]  T0 
INNER JOIN  IGE1 T1 ON T0.[DocDate] = T1.[DocDate] 
where T0.WhsCode = 'RecBay' 
and T0.[DocDate] = '13jan2016' 
and T0.[ItemCode] = 'Abebatest' 
and T0.[Project] = 'GHS01' 
GROUP BY T0.[ItemCode], T0.[Dscription] ,T0.[Project] ,T0.[DocDate] ,T0.[Dscription] ,T0.[Quantity], T1.[Quantity]
```

I am getting following output

```
| # | Item No.  | Item/Service Description | Project Code | Recipts  | Posting Date | Project Code | Issues | ABC      |
|---|-----------|--------------------------|--------------|----------|--------------|--------------|--------|----------|
| 1 | Abebatest | Abebatest                | GHS01        | 100      | 13.01.2016   | GHS01        | 50     | 50       |
| 2 | Abebatest | Abebatest                | GHS01        | 100      | 13.01.2016   | GHS01        | 100    | 0        |
| 3 | Abebatest | Abebatest                | GHS01        | 200      | 13.01.2016   | GHS01        | 50     | 150      |
| 4 | Abebatest | Abebatest                | GHS01        | 200      | 13.01.2016   | GHS01        | 100    | 100      |
| 5 | Abebatest | Abebatest                | GHS01        | 2,000.00 | 13.01.2016   | GHS01        | 50     | 1,950.00 |
| 6 | Abebatest | Abebatest                | GHS01        | 2,000.00 | 13.01.2016   | GHS01        | 100    | 1,900.00 |
```

Comment: Value of what?  The results are definitely unique.  You probably just don't understand the query.  Sample data and desired results would make it possible to help you.

Comment: What? Come on, is this the information what you can share with us? Nice query, however it tells exactly NOTHING about your system, the structure of tables involved, the constraints, etc. Please read [ask] in [help].

Comment: Can you also provide some data and desirable output?

Comment: They are clearly not duplicates. The value of the column `abc` are different in each record.

Comment: if you check query. abc is SUBTRACTION of RECEIETS AND ISSUES

Comment: please focus on RECEIPTS and ISSUES

Comment: Are they different? Yes, they are. Are they satisfy the requirements to be a separate result? Yes. `DISTINCT` is for the whole record, not for the first column only. Use group by if you want grouping.

Comment: Yeah, second that one @Pred - OP should not forget that it's `SELECT DISTINCT ITEMS FROM THIS <select list>`, not `SELECT <select list> FROM DISTINCT RECORDS`

Comment: i am already grouping ..

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx Read it. The first sentence. Read it again. Interpret it. Done? Check your result. Are those unique RECORDS? Concatenate all the fields. Are the result strings different? Yes. Answer some questions pls: What is the goal? What do you want to achieve? What DISTINCT means in this particular case **for you**?

Comment: my goal is to achieve three entries only. because i have entered 1,3,5 rows only. its showing me 6 times. i understood what distinct is. can you please tell me what it should be then?

Comment: Why 1,3,5? What is special in those records? I can not see any difference between those 3 and their pairs except the fact, that the Issues column has different values.

Comment: listen. recieps and issues are different columns. i entered three values for receipts, 100,200,2000 and for issues i entered 50,100,50. they are coming twice.

Comment: OK, let's start it from the baseline: please share us the table structures, the sample values, the goal (**business** definition of the result). It is a good practice to build an SQLFiddle demo and link it to help us to help you. Pretend, that you are the tech lead, who got a small job. Now delegate it to a newbie. Tell the newbie, what and where he/she can find and what is the task to do. Rewrite your question like this pls.

Comment: anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` acts across the whole row, not just on the `ItemCode`.

In your case, all of the records are unique if you compared them column-by-column.

**Update**

`DISTINCT` only returns records of the results set that are unique. For example, if you had the following table:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    1 | b    |
|    2 | c    |
|    2 | c    |
+------+------+
```

And then ran the following script against it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2 FROM TABLE
```

Only rows 1, 2 and 3 would be returned. (Even though `Col1` is the same for rows 1 and 2, `Col2` makes the `row` distinct.)

Finally, `DISTINCT` applies to the results set, not the base tables. This means that in your instance, column `abc`, is the cause of the problem, even though it's a calculated field.

Comment: there is only one entry for 1,3,5 row.. why it is giving me same values for two times

Comment: Its not the same value, columns issue and abc are different @Kirat

Comment: abc is SUBTRACTION of two columns.. can you check query once again

Comment: Yes I did, as I see it, you have in table  ige1 2 rows with those filters, one with quantity 50 and one with 100 and in ign1 you have 3, one with 100, one with 200 and one with 2000 on quantity. You didn't give us desired output and input so we cant know what you want. But your query does what it suppose to @Kirat

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct` eliminates duplicate rows! It means that row is eliminated only if all column values are equal.
It means that there can be 10 times row with same `T0.[ItemCode]` if any other column value is not equal. But there cannot be rows with same values for every column. Also `Group By` cannot eliminate duplicates for single column when it is used on multiple columns.
Do not use `Group By` on `T0.[Quantity], T1.[Quantity]`, use aggregates.